# A simple example of TXT to XML with Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a simple text file displaying data within a list like format (input.txt).

```
Example One
Example Two
Example Three
...
```

What I want to do is use Java to convert this text file into an XML file (output.xml) stating that for each list entry, put it in a tag (such as `<tag>Example One</tag>` for example). I've researched into this, however the results I get are either irrelevant to what I am doing, over-complicates this simple example, or just doesn't provide enough explanation on what I need to do or how the provided solution works.

Can someone help me with what I am trying to accomplish?

Many thanks.

Comment: "I've researched into this" - did you try anything at all based on what you found, even if it was over-complicating the issue?

Comment: I've researched into converting TXT files into XML files with Java, and I get several links which are not answering my question.

Comment: [this link](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/TextToXML.shtml) shows me how to convert an array of strings, which is not what I'm trying to do and doesn't specify how the array is defined (from a text file in this case).

Comment: [this example](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/java/xml/texttoXML.html) gives me an extensive example of how to convert data.txt to data.xml without showing me what data.txt contains so I can't compare or see it working in order to get an understanding on how it works.

Comment: [while this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383104/text-file-to-xml-conversion-java) is a post of someone having an issue with their code, in which someone replies with an answer through a dead link.

Comment: I am currently referring to [this example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0482.html) but I decided to post my query on stack overflow for now.

Comment: The last link seems to do exactly what you want. Doe you have any difficulties understanding it or appliying it to you requeirement? Did you don an attempt based on it?

Comment: It's a working example, I just want to see if I can simplify it first to see if I understand it correctly.

Comment: I don't think that example can get any simpler, it is already very simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There, reads text file (data.txt) and makes it into an XML file (data.xml):

```
import java.io.*;

import org.xml.sax.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.*;

public class ToXML {

    BufferedReader in;
    StreamResult out;
    TransformerHandler th;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ToXML().begin();
    }

    public void begin() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data.txt"));
            out = new StreamResult("data.xml");
            openXml();
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                process(str);
            }
            in.close();
            closeXml();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void openXml() throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, SAXException {

        SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
        th = tf.newTransformerHandler();

        // pretty XML output
        Transformer serializer = th.getTransformer();
        serializer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
        serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

        th.setResult(out);
        th.startDocument();
        th.startElement(null, null, "inserts", null);
    }

    public void process(String s) throws SAXException {
        th.startElement(null, null, "option", null);
        th.characters(s.toCharArray(), 0, s.length());
        th.endElement(null, null, "option");
    }

    public void closeXml() throws SAXException {
        th.endElement(null, null, "inserts");
        th.endDocument();
    }
}
```

From this:

```
Example One
Example Two
Example Three
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inserts>
    <option>Example One</option>
    <option>Example Two</option>
    <option>Example Three</option>
</inserts>
```

Credit goes to [the author of this post](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0482.html). Why can't examples be this simple?

Comment: [You might want to mark your answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). also what Sanjeev has posted is correct.

Comment: I've tried, says I've got to wait for two days for some reason. Thanks for letting me know though.

Answer (score 2):

For this simple thing read your file line by line and apply transformation to the line and write to output.xml, something like this:

```
Open File for reading
Open File for writing.

Loop through Input file {
   String str = <read a line from file>;
   str= str.replaceAll("(.*)","<tag>$1</tag>");
   Write this string to target file.
}

Flush output file.
Close Output file.
Close Input File.
```

Hope this helps you in right direction.

Comment: Please tell the reason for downvoting.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply, and you should not have been down-voted, your answer is relevant to my question.